# How can I move specific user to specific channels with discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I am making a discord bot just for fun with python. I try to move people.
Let me explain [the Duck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgBt3.png) come from "A" have to go to "1" then "2" then come back to "A" .
Do someone have a clue how this works?`await member.move_to(channel, *, reason=None)`
I don't know how to save the Id of a voice channel in a variable

thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save IDs by using Developer Mode (Can be toggled on in Appearance settings).

The snippet works by using the `member` object which can be obtained via:

```
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, *, member = discord.Member):
```

which is then moved to the specified ID.

**Note:** `member = discord.Member` takes the user that was mentioned as an argument. Example:

```
> !command @Duhon
> member = @Duhon
```

To take the user who executed the command, use `ctx.author`

The code you want is multiple of the `move_to` function.

Comment: So.
I did something
`@bot.command()
async def mv(ctx, *, member = discord.Member,channel):
    if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to voice!")
    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Who am I trying to move? Use !move @user")
    await member.move_to(channel)`
And I dont know how / why it send me this error message`TypeError: __new__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'bases' and 'namespace'`
,when I write `!mv @name` me and @name is connect to different chan

Comment: @maevaLeroi Try this snippet:
https://pastebin.com/e8UQ4zd4
Worked for me (replace the IDs). Also, do `import time` if you want to use the 5 second sleeps.